# How to add aws shield to a route 53 via cloudformation?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

adding a custom domain name to an api gateway via cloudformation. see template below, resource include hosted zone, ssl certificate ... is it possible to  aws shield to route 53 .

```
 route53HostedZone:
    Type: AWS::Route53::HostedZone
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Ref Domain
      ....
 cert:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties: 
      DomainName: !Ref Domain
      ValidationMethod: DNS
 Alias:
    Type: AWS::Route53::Recordset
    Properties:
      Type: A
      Name: !Ref Domain
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt ApiConfig
      ...
 ApiConfig:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Properties:
      RegionalCertificateArn:
        Ref: cert
      DomainName:
        Ref: !Ref Domain
 ....
```

Comment: Sadly its not clear what you want to do? Any errors? Can you explain more of what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: @Marcin - primarily , I want to see if i can use aws Shield along with WAF and see if it is possible to do all via cloudformation template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shield Standard is enabled by dafeult and you don't have to do anything to use it in your CFN. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-overview.html):

> All AWS customers benefit from the **automatic** protections of AWS Shield Standard, at no additional charge.